# Ember - how to make component an empty tag?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

```
tagName: 'img' produces `<img></img>`.
```

Is there a way to prevent this? I know I could just create a div and put the img inside, but creating the img right away is more convenient for me and I dont need to create any template for the component.
Thanks for any input.

Comment: What is the result you are trying to obtain? Do you want `<img />`?

Comment: yes, both <img> or <img /> seem semantically ok for me. Probably even <img></img> causes no harm, but it just seems weird to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5405) which indicates that the ember core team is aware of the behavior for self closing tags but probably will not change this behavior before Ember 2.0.

See the quote by @trek in the issue I've linked to:

> The documentation is accurate. This is just a bug that hopefully we
>   can address in 2.0. I'm closing this particular issue since it was re:
>   docs. I know @mmun and @mixonic are aware of this general problem.

I wouldn't worry too much. I'll quote @mixonic from the same issue:

> This is correct, a view that is based on a self-closing DOM node
>   cannot by definition contain more DOM

So it doesn't seem that anything will be accidentially inserted between the opening and closing tags.